# Clear Laravel cache(s) without Artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I've moved my project but have run into an issue. I'm discovering that the old settings (which have been changed in my `.env` to reflect the changed host) are still being used by my project.

I can't access my project through a browser as it returns this error: `` SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'appReop'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `settings` limit 1) ``

`appReop` was the previous login username. And while I could just create a new user to reflect this, I also run into an issue about the old password being too weak for the current database configuration.

When I go to run php artisan cache:clear, it returns the same above error. So I was curious if there was a way to manually clear the caches to fix my errors?

### Update

This shows the three errors that pop up after running any Artisan command:

[image]

Comment: As [Andrey Mikhalev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7228796/andrey-mikhalev) says, try wrapping your password with single quotes.
I hope this help someone.

Answer (score 20):

Not sure you have solved this, my suggestion is remove the files inside below folder. So the database connection cache file will create again after removed. (Laravel 5)

```
/<root>/bootstrap/cache/*
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: This saved me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can call an Artisan command outside the CLI.

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
   $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
   // return what you want
});
```

You can check the official doc here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#calling-commands-outside-of-cli

Comment: upvote just for thinking outside of the box!

Answer (score 2):

It's one time only? Just delete the folder `storage/framework/cache/data`

Comment: Yes, it is one time only. And unfortunately, I deleted the folder prior to this and nothing had happened.

Comment: Seems this is not a cache issue, but configuration. Look for credentials at `config/database.php`

Comment: I've changed those too in the hopes that it was that. But after changing everything it is still somehow relying on caching somewhere as it still tries to connect using the old credentials.

Comment: I've tried that but it continues to give the error. I've tried all of the artisan commands at this point to do with caching.

Comment: And I should clarify that it is giving me the error in the console as well, not just the web browser

Answer (score 1):

If someone still has such problem, check out your password for database. It seems like .env file does not accept # sign, that's why I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
php artisan down
php artisan config:clear
```

As this will place Laravel in maintenance mode and then clear only the config setting cache.

@Filippe commented about this already.

**Update**

Just create a file called down like in the picture below then run `php artisan config:clear` and then if it works `php artisan up`.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question with a screenshot, but at this moment, no artisan commands work. That's why I'm hoping to try and locate the issue either in caches or code... :/

Comment: Try creating a file called down in `storage\framework` this should put Laravel into maintenance mode manually.

Answer (score 0):

rather batter if you could provide permission to your storage directory.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage
```

then remove cache and using `php artisan cache:clear`.I hope this will help you.